# Difference between Spec $k[x,y]/(y-x^2)$ and Spec $k[x,y]/((y-x^2)^2)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes

I know from Hartshorne (II.5.10), they are two different closed subschemes in the affine plane Spec $k[x,y]$. But it seems to me they have the same underlying topological space, which is the curve $y=x^2$ and the generic point. So I guess they should have different structure sheaves separately ($\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec } k[x,y]/(y-x^2)}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec } k[x,y]/(y-x^2)^2}$).

Am I right? and how to see this result better? (how those two sheaves are different...) Thank you!!

Comment: What's wrong with the description $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}R}=\tilde{R}$ (or equivalently, $\Gamma(\operatorname{Spec}R,\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}R})=R$)?

Comment: Note that $k[x,y]/(y-x^2) \cong k[x]$ and $k[x,y]/(y-x^2)^2 \cong k[x,z]/(z^2)$.

Comment: @ Magdiragdag Thanks!

Comment: Similar Spec but different coordinate ring (or sheaf of regular functions). (There is a morphism between the two which is bijective on the points $\in Spec$)